# two 3d model rendering error in three.js when im trying to render only one

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, chakra-ui

In my portfolio app, I'm trying to render a 3d model however when rendering, two canvases are being created as you can see in the below console image. I'm a beginner in Three.js so I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please help me understand what should I.

[image]

below is the code that renders the model, can anyone please help me understand how can I render only one canvas.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { Box, Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { loadGLTFModel } from "../lib/model";

function easeOutCircle(x) {
    return Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(x - 1, 4))

}

const AnimeChar = () => {

    const refContainer = useRef()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState()
    const [_camera, setCamera] = useState()
    const [target] = useState(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 1.2, 0))
    const [initialCameraPosition] = useState(
        new THREE.Vector3(
            20 * Math.sin(0.2 * Math.PI),
            10,
            20 * Math.cos(0.2 * Math.PI)
        )
    )
    const [scene] = useState(new THREE.Scene())
    const [_controls, setControls] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const { current: container } = refContainer
        if (container && !renderer) {
            const scW = container.clientWidth
            const scH = container.clientHeight

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true,
                alpha: true

            })
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
            renderer.setSize(scW, scH)
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
            setRenderer(renderer)

            // 640->240
            // 8->6
            const scale = scH * 0.005 + 4.8
            const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
                -scale,
                scale,
                scale,
                -scale,
                0.01,
                50000

            )
            camera.position.copy(initialCameraPosition)
            camera.lookAt(target)
            setCamera(camera)

            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 1)
            scene.add(ambientLight)
            const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
            controls.autoRotate = true
            controls.target = target
            setControls(controls)

            loadGLTFModel(scene, '/dog.glb', { receiveShadow: false, castShadow: false }).then(() => {
                animate()
                setLoading(false)
            })

            let req = null
            let frame = 0
            const animate = () => {
                req = requestAnimationFrame(animate)

                frame = frame <= 100 ? frame +11 : frame

                if (frame <= 100) {
                    const p = initialCameraPosition
                    const rotSpeed = easeOutCircle(frame / 120) * Math.PI * 20

                    camera.position.y = 10
                    camera.position.x = p.x * Math.cos(rotSpeed) + p.z * Math.sin(rotSpeed)
                    camera.position.z = p.z * Math.cos(rotSpeed) - p.x * Math.sin(rotSpeed)
                    camera.lookAt(target)
                }

                else{
                    controls.update()
                }
                renderer.render(scene,camera)
            }
            return () => {
                cancelAnimationFrame(req)
                renderer.dispose()
            }
        }

    }, [])

    return (
        <Box ref={refContainer} className="AnimeChar" m='auto'
            at={['20px', '-60px', '-120px']}
            mb={['-40px', '-140px', '-200px']}
            w={[280, 480, 640]}
            h={[280, 480, 640]}
            position='relative'>
            {loading && (
                <Spinner size="xl" position='absolute'
                    left="50%"
                    top="50%"
                    ml="calc(0px - var(--spinner-size)/2)"
                    mt="calc(0px-var(--spinner-size))"
                />
            )}


        </Box>
    )
}

export default AnimeChar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you use [react-three fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) instead?

Your whole setup would then be something like this:

```xml
<Canvas>
  <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
  <directionalLight color="red" position={[0, 0, 5]} />
  <mesh>
    <boxGeometry />
    <meshStandardMaterial />
  </mesh>
</Canvas>
```

Then you can use gltf-to-jsx to convert your model directly to a JSX component.